# Get parameters for specific template inside a library file

Tags: joomla-2.5, templates

Is it possible to get parameters for a specific template (not the active template necessarily)?

Any advice would be appreciated.

//edit
The template WILL NOT be active, so I need to get the template's parameters without:

```
$app = JFactory::getApplication('site');
$template = $app->getTemplate(true);
$param = $template->params->get('paramName', defaultValue);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it like this:

```
$db = JFactory::getDbo();
$query = $db->getQuery(true);
$query  ->select('params')
        ->from('#__template_styles')
        ->where('`template` = ' . $db->q('beez3')) // Just replace 'beez3' with with the name of your template
        ->where('client_id = 0'); // client_id = 0 for SITE and client_id = 1 for ADMIN templates
$db->setQuery($query);
$params = json_decode($db->loadResult());
echo $params->wrapperSmall; // replace wrapperSmall with desired parameter key
```

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 3):

To get the active template parameters, you can use the following:

*Code by @GDP* ([source](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11493168/joomla-2-5-accessing-template-parameters-in-components-template))

```
$template = JFactory::getApplication()->getTemplate(true);
$params   = $template->params;
$variable = $params->get('variable');
```

However I would not recommend getting parameters from non-active template. Instead I suggest you set default values, for example.

```
$variable = $params->get('colour', '#FFFFFF');
```

Comment: Like I said, the template will most probably not be active due to some plugin I have that changes the template assignment.

Comment: If you include more specifics about your situation in your question, the programmers might be able to offer the more detailed solution.  I didn't get from your question that you would be assigning templates to pages and that's why it's not necessarily active. Edit: you probably mean to use the DEFAULT active template for the site, right?